# How to detect tab change event in BHO using C#?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, tabs, bho, ieaddon

This is my 4th consecutive question regarding BHO

I have developed a BHO using C# and its running fine. I have used OnDocumentComplete function.

Now I want to call this function when user changes his/her tab in IE.

I have gone through so many links , didn't get a proper response

As well as I wanna know the ways if I can boost my Addon performance.
Its taking little more time execute completely.

I appreciate for any help.

Thanks,

Anuj.

Comment: It seems no body has the idea to do it :( .

Comment: It's a complex subject. Example: in recent version of IE, each BHO will run in it's own low level process. What do you try to achieve?

Comment: Hi Manuell. Thanks for reply. I just need to track current URL of active tab URL.

Comment: Doable in a BHO, but complex. Involves Hooking message (WM_SETFOCUS). Is the function you want to call related to your BHO? I mean, what will do the function?

Comment: As I have told , already implemented OnDocumentComplete function and there I am checking the URL with web service. So If I'll get URL of tab of which I clicked I'll be able to do what I want. :)

Basically I wanna execute my code whatever have written under OnDocumentComplete in tab change event.

I have used windowstatechange function, but now dont think so it will work for my case.

Have I cleared your question ?

Comment: Sorry to be late. Use @manuell when responding, please. I don't understand your problem but I'm willing to help. We have to chat. Leave a comment with a GMT time for a "rendez vous" here.

Comment: @manuell. Yaa we should chat. Mine time is 5:07 PM (GMT +5:30 India).

Comment: Argh, I have just realized that I don't know how to start a chat. I think it's an option when there is too much comments. Let's comment :-)

Comment: We need more comments

Comment: Do you know how to start a chat?

Comment: I will soon go to lunch. How is the weather where you live?

Comment: I will be here at 10:00 AM GMT (11 AM in France, 5:30 PM for you)

Comment: @manuell Today at what you're available to chat?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment today. Will try to be here tomorrow (Tuesday) at 11:00 AM GMT

Comment: @manuell are you there ? Can you share your skype username or yahoo email address to anuj.sri86@gmail.com

Comment: Is this really impossible?

Comment: It's possible. Did you get my email from 19/12/2013?

Comment: @manuell Hi I'll get back to you after 5 hour. Thanks